# React Native Firebase Push Notification iOS Real Device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Im quite new react mobile development. I tried push notifications with firebase. It working nice on android emulator/real device. But its not working on ios real device. I've been trying to find a solution for this issue in 3 days. Please help me. Also, i added apns key in firebase and xcode capabilities backgroundmodes and push notifications.

```js
My AppDelegate.mm :

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"
#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];

  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  NSDictionary *appProperties = [RNFBMessagingModule addCustomPropsToUserProps:nil withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

```js
Firebase Functions:
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    GetFCMToken();
  }
}

async function GetFCMToken(){
  let fcmToken=await AsyncStorage.getItem("fcmToken");
  console.log(fcmToken,"old token");
  if(!fcmToken){
    try {
      const fcmToken=await messaging().getToken();
      if(fcmToken){
        console.log(fcmToken,"new token");
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("fcmToken", fcmToken);
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error,"error");
    }
  }
}
export const NotificationListener=()=>{

  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
    console.log(
      'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
      remoteMessage.notification,
    );
  });

  messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage=>{
    console.log("notification on forground state", remoteMessage);
  });

  // Check whether an initial notification is available
  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then(remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
          remoteMessage.notification,
        );
      }
    });

}
```

```js
app.js
async function registerAppWithFCM() {
  if (!messaging().isDeviceRegisteredForRemoteMessages) {
    await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
  }
}

const App: () => Node = () => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    registerAppWithFCM();
    requestUserPermission();
    NotificationListener();
  },[])
```

```js
index.js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have done or tried. Add some more detail.

Comment: i added please take a look

Answer (score 0):

need to enable push notification and background modes in xcode.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7MVF.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8tp7.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7MVF.png)

Comment: i already add this capabilities. but still not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).